# Function defining ways in JS

Tags: javascript, function, call

What kind of function is this, and how do I call it:

```
window.bla = function() {}
```

Is it the same as an on-load function or is it the same as prototyping..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's neither, it's just a global variable with the name `bla`. It'd be the same as `bla = function() {}`.

Prototyping looks like this:

```
var Example = function() {
    return this;
};

Example.prototype.bla = function() {};
```

On-load looks like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    // stuff here
};
```

Comment: Unless there is a `var bla` somewhere.

Comment: If you stick bla into some scope below a `var bla`, yes, otherwise it's the exact same.

Answer (score 3):

This can be called using `window.bla()`. The function is assigned to a property of the `window` variable. This is the same as declaring the function as `function bla(){}` as by default functions are created on the global window object.

This is not the same as prototyping because it is adding the function to a single instance of a window object, not to all object of that type.

Comment: … unless you define `function bla(){}` inside another function.

Comment: Functions are not by default created on the global window object, they're scoped and are like declaring it as `var blah = function(){}`

Answer (score 2):

If you're in the global scope, then you'll be able to call it just by doing *****:

```
bla();
```

If you're not, you can also do:

```
window.bla();
```

***** you can do bla() in any scope, except for those scopes where there is another bla variable already defined. You can find a quick example here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matiasarriola/ht38u/)

I strongly recommend this: http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#4

This way of defining a function has nothing to do with the prototype.

Comment: You can `bla()` in any scope — just so long as there isn't another `bla()` is a narrower scope.

Comment: @quentin thanks, updated the question to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 1):

This is assigning a `bla` property to the `window` object. This is not an onload function. It just binds the function to `window.bla`.

It can be called like this:

`window.bla()`